# distribute iOS app through enterprise program

Tags: ios

I can download the IPA file from browser but not from iPad. I followed all the instruction mentioned http://johannesluderschmidt.de/provision-ios-ipa-app-for-in-house-enterprise-distribution/2993/. Any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You do not only need the .ipa file, but also the .plist. And the .plist needs to be served over HTTPS (as of iOS 7.1, IIRC). It seems your site does not support HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for your help..I really appreciate it.  I am going to have the HTTPS.

Comment: Have you used `diawi.com`? Its kinda good.

Comment: I second Hemang's comment. Diawi is pretty awesome. I always use it to distribute my enterprise app. Air Watch is also good but more cumbersome. Diawi is all about simple upload & sharing urls.